# Full text search catalog name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I want to find the name of full text search catalog on my SQL Server 2008 database. How can I do that using SQl Server Management Studio or TSQL. I tried using:

```
SELECT FullTextServiceProperty('IsFullTextInstalled')
```

and it returns 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query will help:

```
select name, *
from sys.fulltext_catalogs
```

You can have more than one full-text search catalog, so the query will return all of them. The one that is default will have `is_default = 1`.

Comment: @Alex Thanks. I tried above query and it returned one record but in that record is_default = 0 Should there be a default full text catalog ? Also is Full text search catalog per database or per SQL server instance ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow - full-text search catalogs are per database, not per server instance. The reason why `is_default = 0`, because you didn't mark catalog as default when you created one.

Comment: @Alex how can I make it default ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow - in SSMS UI: go to `Storage` => `Full Text Catalogs`, right click on the catalog select `Properties`. Set `Defatult Catalog` to `true`.

Comment: Or you can run `alter fulltext catalog FullTextCatalogName as default`.